# How to get/store value outside from GenericHandler

Tags: java, handler

How to get/store some value from GenericHandler and what will be the correct way? 
At handleRequest,handleResponse is builded a String what i need to use only later.

Thanks

Comment: give more details please

Comment: I got a Custom handler who are extending GenericHandler, i added my handler to handler chain, handler are working on request,response,fault build some log msg what i need later store to DB, The problem is that i dont know how to get theese msg what was builded in handler....

Comment: Not clear for me. sorry. give a dump code snapshot

Comment: similar to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21454_01/html/821-2600/dsgn_impl_cstm_hndlrs_t.html#custom_handler) and at the end i got a builded String

Comment: I see, but what is our issue hier